# Добавить код в работающее приложение

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

Нужно иметь возможность добавить в работающую программу небольшой код, который будет сохранён как функция, и который можно будет в дальнейшем вызывать по ссылке.

Видел нечто похожее в приложении Animator Demo, но, копаясь в исходниках, так и не нашел, где этот код заносится в приложение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В то же время не хочется давать юзеру полную свободу действий, и как-нибудь ограничить функционал до переменных, всяких if, for, и вызова некоторых других функций.

Подскажите какой-нибудь пример решения подобной задачи, ибо я пока вообще не представляю, как это должно выглядеть.

Да, и ещё: юзер будет вводить свою функцию в `textbox`, в приложение, написанное на C#, которое будет передавать текст в мою DLL, написанную на C++.

Comment: Это компиляция в режиме выполнения. Получаете текущую сборку, компилируете код из строки, и добавляете новый объект в сборку. По сути, чем-то на рефлексию будет походить.

Comment: Ну и, функцию вы добавить не сможете, только класс, а уже в классе можно мудрить и функции и всё что пожелаете. Для ограничений функционала класса, можете обязать наследовать свой интерфейс или абстракцию, или вообще, дать пользователю только оформлять функцию ,а остальное (неймспейс и шапку фунции с прочей информацией) нагенерить автоматически, разве что, "пользователь" в таком подходе сможет заинжектить что нибудь что вы не ожидаете)

Comment: Вот, рекомендую ознакомиться https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: Только, сразу скажу, лично я столкнулся с одной специфической трудностью - всё что будет "докомпилированно" в runtime, останется там навсегда, пока работает программа. То есть, в шарпе не предусмотрена очистка сборки. И удалять то что вы компилите в рунтайме - нельзя :(

Comment: @test123 мне, в общем то, без разницы, можно удалять или нет. юзер будет писать свои команды, и если нужно, то просто удалит не нужную команду. А перед закрытием приложение будет сохранять все пользовательские функций, которые будут загружены при старте. Спасибо за инфу, почитаю.

Comment: А сейчас прочитал вопрос полностью. Докомпилить вы сможете только в шарпе. Из плюсов такое провернуть, теоретически, реально, но, практически.... вам придётся таскать компилятор, более того, библиотеки + это всё выглядит очень сомнительно. Рекомендую ограничится шарпом. Если вы хотите дёргать что то из функций своей длл - пробрасывайте их в шарпе, пускай сборка шарпа вызывает проброшенные функции. То есть, языка останется 2, но, компилировать будет шарповый код, а не плюсовый.

Comment: А может быть вам подойдет вариант встроить в своё приложение интерпретатор Lua? Сам не пробовал, но похоже, что он интегрируется очень малыми усилиями. Пара ссылок для общего представления: [пуньк](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237503/), [пыньк](https://habrahabr.ru/post/197262/).

Comment: Стоит посмотреть в сторону JIT-компиляции. Для этого можно приспособить, например, связку *Clang + библиотека LLVM*.